# Forms created dynamically in jquery does not submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I am creating a number of forms in my page dynamically. Here is my form creation routine in jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var quest;
$.ajax({
        url: "myteacher.php",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        quest = response;
                        var forms = [];
                        for(i=0; i<quest.length; i++)
                        {
                            $("#unanswered").append("<p>"+quest[i].qtext+"</p>");
                            forms[i] = $('<form method = "POST">').attr('id', function(){
                                return 'AnswerBox'+quest[i].questionid;
                            }).appendTo($("#unanswered"));
                            $('<textarea rows="5" class="AnswerBoxArea" name="answer">').appendTo(forms[i]);

                            $('<input type="button" value="Answer" class="AnsSubmit">').attr('id', function(){
                                return 'AnsTextQ'+quest[i].questionid;
                            }).appendTo(forms[i]);

                        }

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status+",  " + jqXHR.statusText+",  "+textStatus+",  "+errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

});

The form is created perfectly. But no event is initiated on clicking the buttons. I was testing the same using the following routine:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(":button").on("click", function(){
$("input[id^='AnsTextQ']").each(function() {
        var x = $(this).attr('type');
        alert(x);
    });
});
```

});

Can somebody tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
The problem is that your function to the `.on("click"` event kicks off in memory when the elements as `":button"` do not yet exist, so these are like `undefined` selectors for this need to adapt the logic of your code to run when the element exists. Example is to use the function `.on()` go jQuery [jQuery .on() function api](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this select the item where it already exists in your `DOM`.

This work in an button which is added after into `DOM`.
Try with this, and tell me.

```
$(document).on("click", ":button", function(){
$("input[id^='AnsTextQ']").each(function() {
  var x = $(this).attr('type');
  alert(x);
});
```

Comment: It did not work. But when I slightly modified it $(document).on("click", ":button", function() it works. So where the problem was?

Comment: @soumyajyoti change `.on("sumbit"` to `.on("click"`

Comment: @soumyajyoti sorry, it is because your button isn't `type='submit'`, my mistake not see in the code, sorry. then if it's with that modification?

Comment: It is working. If you could also explain what the original problem in my code was.

Comment: @soumyajyoti finish, I hope to explain properly and you can understand.

Comment: that was prompt, precise and perfect